# Wrong coordinate system after import

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-maps-api, belgium

I try to do something simple, use official data of Belgium zones that I found here: https://eservices.minfin.fgov.be/myminfin-web/pages/cadastral-plans.

So I downloaded the files of one city and opened it in QGIS. That works but the coordinate system seems to be totally wrong. I would like to switch to an international standard.

In fact, I need to use the Googlemap API to get coordinates from full addresses and use that to get the position. Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: I downloaded a random file and see that the projection is `PROJCS["Belge_Lambert_1972",GEOGCS["GCS_Belge_1972",DATUM["D_Belge_1972",SPHEROID["International_1924",6378388,297]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199432955]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",150000.01256],PARAMETER["False_Northing",5400088.4378],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",4.367486666666666],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",49.8333339],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",51.16666733333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",90],UNIT["Meter",1]]`  which might not be want you want.

Comment: But that doesn't make it `incorrect`.  It isn't a custom CRS and is described in the EPSG database ~ http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370

Comment: There is a very good reason why cadastral data would be in a projected system and not a geographic one: their goal is to measure lengths and areas, for which a system where units are angular would perform very poorly. As such, the CRS of the data is actually the **right** one. You can always reproject the data though.

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded a random shapefile from your link and plotted it against a basemap:

[image]

The coordinate system is fine. Perhaps you can provide an example of a shapefile that you think is incorrect.

As for your second questions about getting coordinates: if you want lat/lon, the most common coordinate reference system (CRS) to use is EPSG:4326. You can transform your shapefile(s) into 4326 using the "Reproject layer" tool in the "Vector general" QGIS toolbox. You say you want to use the coordinates to "get the position," but the coordinates *are* the position so I'm not sure what you mean exactly.